# how can I limit the maximum of the number of variables (sql variables) to 100

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a view table which has the following

```
CAST(ROUND(SUM(dbo.TR.Score * 100) AS int) AS ScoreReached
```

I want to limit the number of ScoreReached to only 100 (cannot larger than 100)

can i do that?

Comment: By "limit the number of ScoreReached", do you mean that you want to limit the number of results the query will return to the first 100 results ?
If not, can you provide more information and context to your question ?

Comment: View or table? Those are two different things.... You can define a **CHECK** constraint on a **table** - e.g. limit the allowable column values to 0-100 - and by doing so, any *view* that uses this table's column with the check constraint will also show values only from 0-100 ...

Comment: hi, thanks for ur answers.

and a learn a new function thanks @marc_s 

what i mean is, if the variables is >=100, then it will automatics changes to 100. and i want to do it in a "view table".

Comment: This **isn't** a variable - it's a table (or view) **column** ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 100 CAST(ROUND(SUM(dbo.TR.Score * 100) AS int) AS ScoreReached
FROM MyTable
```

If I understood your question right.
This is syntax for TSQL, you can check syntax for others [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You could use *CASE ... WHEN* syntax to constraint the value of ScoreReached column

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN TBL.ScoreReached > 100 THEN 100 
         ELSE TBL.ScoreReached 
       END AS ScoreReached
FROM   (SELECT CAST(ROUND(SUM(dbo.TR.Score * 100), 0) AS INT) AS ScoreReached 
        FROM   <your table name>) TBL
```